# Creating a html form and using javascript to access a python script within?

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms

I created a python script that basically given a csv file that lists the students in a particular school and the subjects they are each taking, prints out the percent of people taking any given subject(s).

Now, I have to create a html form for the user to enter in the information, instead of just running prompts from the script. In essence, I would double click on the html file and then the form it displays would ask to choose a school from a drop down menu, and enter the subject(s) that I wanted to search for, then finally display the percent of people that for example are taking calculus and literature on the page when I click the submit button. It doesn't have to be on the internet or anything, just run from the html file.

My problem here however, is that I have only been programming for a little while, and my knowledge of Javascript is limited. I know how to create the form with HTML and CSS.

However how do I implement the Javascript to access the python code? And do I actually require a python web framework since I'm not putting this on the internet? If it would be easier, I am also considering re-writing the python script into Javascript(is that a better option?), but I want to know how to do it with the python script.

Basically, I'm not quite sure how to implement this and what languages I would need to do this, so can anyone give me an idea of how I could do this?

Comment: My advice would be to rewrite your script in javascript.

Comment: @zord, I think I might consider that, thanks

Comment: @nathanhayfield If I used javascript would I still need to use ajax and jquery? Sorry, I know these are really basic questions, I just don't have much experience haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go ahead an evaluate python in the browser (with [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/)), but it seems like a lot of overhead just so you can run a snippet of code.

Take it as an opportunity to learn some javascript!

Comment: Oh, so even if I did it with python I wouldn't require a web framework?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "web framework". Skulpt is a js library that executes python code in the browser. You can use jquery if you want, but ultimately what you are trying to do is possible with plain js. It would probably help to do some basic js tutorials before trying to solve a specific problem. http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

Comment: Oh with web framework, I meant something like [web.py](http://webpy.org/). But in any case thank you, I think I will be re-writing it into javascript!

Comment: Good luck! BTW, there is also Google AppEngine, which can use python. https://cloud.google.com/appengine